# Arithmetic projective duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry, duality

Projective duality is a duality that associates to a (smooth) subvariety X of $\mathbb{P}^n$ the dual variety $X^*\subset\mathbb{P}^{n*}$ of tangent hyperplanes.

What makes the duality interesting is that if we work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero it is an actual duality, i.e. $(X^*)^*=X$.

Are there are references that analyse projective duality over not algebraically closed base fields or even dedekind schemes?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Since $X^*$ is typically singular, what do you mean by $(X^*)^*$?

Comment: Take the closure of the variety obtained taking tangent hyperplanes on the smooth locus.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, over any field of characteristic $2$, there is a standard example of a smooth conic $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ and a point $a \in \mathbb{P}^2$ such that all lines going through $a$ are tangent to $\mathcal{C}$.

Hence, the projective dual to $\mathcal{C}$ is not integral. In the comments below, Noam notices that $\mathcal{C}^*$ is $a^{\perp}$ with multiplicity $2$. Hence the dual of $\mathcal{C}^*$ is not even well-defined.

Comment: Not $a^\perp$ with multiplicity $2$?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies : you are right, $\mathcal{C}^*$ is $a^{\perp}$ with multiplicity $2$. Hence the dual of $\mathcal{C}^*$ is not even well-defined.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but aren't you saying that that there is an example in char 2 of a conic whose projective dual is a double line? So the projective dual is well defined but the conic won't be the dual of its dual. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @Bear : how do you define the projective dual of a double line?